# Difference between "Environment Groups" and "Groups"

Tags: linux, rhel, linux-kernel, yum

When I run `yum grouplist`, I get below output:

```
[root@rhel-85 ~]# yum grouplist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                     10 kB/s | 4.5 kB     00:00    
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)                                                    2.1 MB/s |  38 MB     00:17    
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)                                                       8.7 kB/s | 4.1 kB     00:00    
Available Environment Groups:
   Server
   Minimal Install
   Workstation
   Virtualization Host
   Custom Operating System
Installed Environment Groups:
   Server with GUI
Installed Groups:
   Container Management
   Headless Management
Available Groups:
   RPM Development Tools
   .NET Core Development
   Scientific Support
   Smart Card Support
   Security Tools
   Development Tools
   Legacy UNIX Compatibility
   Network Servers
   Graphical Administration Tools
   System Tools
```

Please help me understand difference between `Environment Groups` and `Groups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group is a list of packages. For example *Container Management* contains `podman`, `buildah` and few other.

An environment is a list of groups. One of the groups in *Server with GUI* is *Container Management*, that's why you have it installed.

In the end there is no difference between groups and environments -- `yum` will just install all packages defined in some XML. These exists mostly to make installation easier and to create some default installation images (e.g. "Server" or "Workstation" ISO). Installation is also the first place where [you can see these](https://access.redhat.com/webassets/avalon/d/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Installation_Guide-en-US/images/eb0ac9cae5aad455eed6c6a8caa0852f/pkg-group.png) -- you choose one environment and you can add some "extra" groups to that.

You can check [Fedora Comps](https://pagure.io/fedora-comps) (which is a list of groups and environments) if you want to check all available groups and environments (some are hidden in the `yum` output). As far as I know RHEL Comps are not publicly available, but [ELN](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/eln/) comps should be close enough.